# CSS transitions for content loading

Tags: javascript, css

I'm implementing some animations on my `HTML5` project with `CSS3` and so far so good. I can do, for example:

```
#someDivId {
    position: absolute;
    background:rgba(255,0,0,0.75);
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}   
#someDivId:hover {
    background:rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
```

And this will change the opacity of my red `div` from `0.75` to `1`. This work for other properties of the div on hover too, like the `color` attribute or even the `border-radius`.

My problem comes with attributes changed automatically when I manipulate the `DOM` with `JavaScript`, like the change in `height` or `width` that happens when an `src` is added to an `img` or if some content is added to a `div`.

For the image case, I have the folowing CSS:

```
.someImageClass {
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 15px;
    border-style: solid;
    max-height:370px;
    max-width:370px;
    transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
```

And the image is loaded to the `DOM` dynamically with JavaScript:

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = someSourceURL;
image.className = "someImageClass";
document.getElementById("someDiv").appendChild(image);
```

At first the image just appears as a square on the container `DIV`. When the img is not done loading it's content, it looks like this:

[image: Image not loaded]

But when the content src is loaded, it looks like this:

[image: Image loaded]

I get no animations between the states.

There were at least two changes of size for the `img` that I identify, one from being nothing (no size, no style) and having its style applied (some size depending on style) and the second from being a node with no content but margin and size to one with its content loaded and a new size. I'm more concerned about the second one, and I'm not sure if the first one technically happens.

Is there a way to handle this kind of size changes triggered by manipulation of the content of a node just with `CSS` selectors and transitions?

Comment: Well  you are just adding an image to the page, no css transition occurs from loading. You can hide the image or make it transparent then once it is loaded add a class to it so it fade in

Comment: this might happen because animations can't run to/from an implicit `auto` value: you should animate from 0 to <image size> that you can read via js

Comment: @Huangism Thanks. You're right probably there's no transition happening. My question is more around having a transition for the change of size that occurs when the content of anode is manipulated with JS.

Comment: @buzoherbert then you would need to set the image width or height to 0 then once the image is loaded, change the width and height to the proper value (you can try auto and see if it works)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the CSS class name once the image is appended in side div.

You can achieve by using setTimeout function.

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.src = someImageClass;
document.getElementById("someDiv").appendChild(image);
setTimeout(function(){
    image.className = "someImageClass";
},1);
```

Or in Jquery

```
$('#someDiv').html('<img src="' + someImagePath + '" />');
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#someDiv img').addClass("someImageClass");
},1);
```